# window.event.cancelBubble=true для FF

Tags: javascript

чето не догоняю я как застопорить всплывание для FF

```
function alllclose() {
    var els = document.getElementsByClassName('okno');
    for( var i=0; i<els.length; ++i ) {
         els[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
        stop_bubbling(event);
    };

    function stop_bubbling(e) {
    if (e && e.stopPropagation) //если метод stopPropagation поддерживается
    e.stopPropagation()
    else
    event.cancelBubble=true
    }
```

работает везде кроме фф

Comment: в функции stop_bubbling добавьте еще e.cancelBubble=true

Comment: везде подабавлял... нифика... если не трудно как эта функция должна выглядеть?

Comment: > Use event.stopPropagation() instead of this non-standard method.

Comment: как именно... пробую не получается

Comment: @ustal, НЕ ЗАБЫВАЙТЕ! Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).@ustal, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: А где `event` определён, вижу что с ним идён вызов stop_bubbling но его нет в параметрах `alllclose`? Кстати, в stop_bubbling нужно не `event` а `e` (предпоследняя строка).

Answer (score 1):

Если я ни чего не путаю то надо так:

```
e.onselectstart=false; //Запрещяет выделение
```